# How to Count Vowels and Consonants in an Input Using Arrays?

Tags: python, arrays, list, char

This is my assignment:

> Write a program which reads in text from the keyboard until '!' is found.
>
> Using an array of integers subscripted by the letters 'A' through 'Z',
>   count the number occurrences of each letter (regardless of whether it
>   is upper or lower case). In a separate counter, also count the total
>   number of "other" characters.
>
> Print out the count for each letter found. Also, print the count of the non-letter 
>   characters.
>
> By inspecting the array, print out the count of the number of vowels,
>   and the number of consonants.

and this is my code:

```
msg = input("What is your message? ")

print ()

num_alpha = 26
int_array = [0] * num_alpha
vowel = [0] * 10000
consanant = [0] * 10000

for alpha in range(num_alpha):
    int_array[alpha] = chr(alpha + 65)
    if int_array[alpha] == 'A' or int_array[alpha] == 'E' or int_array[alpha] == 'I' or int_array[alpha] == 'O' or int_array[alpha] == 'U':
        vowel[alpha] = int_array[alpha]
        print(vowel[alpha])
    else:
        consanant[alpha] = int_array[alpha]



print()

lett = 0
otherch = 0
num_vowels = 0
num_consanants = 0

count_character = [0] * 100000

length = len(msg)

for character in msg.upper():
    if character == "!":
        otherch = otherch + 1
        count_character[ord(character)] = count_character[ord(character)] + 1
        break
    elif character < "A" or character > "Z":
        otherch = otherch + 1
        count_character[ord(character)] = count_character[ord(character)] + 1
    else:
        lett = lett + 1
        count_character[ord(character)] = count_character[ord(character)] + 1
        if vowel[(alpha)] == (character):
            num_vowels = num_vowels + 1
            print(vowel[alpha])
        else:
            num_consanants = num_consanants + 1

print("Number of Letters =", lett)
print("Number of Other Characters = ", otherch)
print("Number of Vowels = ", num_vowels)
print("Number of Consanants = ", num_consanants)


for character in msg.upper():
        print("Character", character, "appeared" , count_character[ord(character)] , "time(s).")
        if character == "!":
            break
```

Every time I input a string it does not recognize vowels. If i were to input "abe!" it would print:

```
Number of Letters = 3 
Number of Other Characters =  1 
Number of Vowels=  0 
Number of Consanants =  3 
Character A appeared 1 time(s). 
Character B appeared 1 time(s). 
Character E appeared 1 time(s).
Character ! appeared 1 time(s).
```

Comment: The assignment is poorly written. You can't subscript an 'array' with a string. Also another hint: the number 10000 shouldn't be appearing in your code.

Comment: what number should i be using then? the number of character in the ascii table?

Comment: Is this assignment meant to be done in Python or in C?  It reads like the person who wrote it has never touched Python.

Comment: @user You shouldn't need any such numbers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here you need to assign `alpha`. Otherwise, it will take the last value of your `for` loop at the top (so it will be 25).

```
else:
    lett = lett + 1
    count_character[ord(character)] = count_character[ord(character)] + 1
    alpha = ord(character) - ord('A') # <-- need this
    if vowel[(alpha)] == (character):
        num_vowels = num_vowels + 1
        print(vowel[alpha])
    else:
        num_consanants = num_consanants + 1
```

Comment: I recommend still into looking the answer Stephan has given, since it will help you to understand the easier, more concise way to do this.

Answer (score 2):

```
if vowel[(alpha)] == (character):
  num_vowels = num_vowels + 1
  print(vowel[alpha])
```

In this code, your alpha is out of scope, that means alpha will be whatever it was on the last iteration of the previous for loop

Also i would recommend a better way of checking for vowels using `in`

```
vowels = ['a','e','i','o','u']
char = 'a'
if char in vowels:
  pass              # you have found a vowel
```

Comment: @user2680935 i dont think it was doing what you thought it was doing.  I'd recommend changing how you check for vowels

Comment: You could shorten it further to just `char in 'aeiou'`.

Comment: @antimony I don't endorse hard coding in this case